# How to "mosaic" rasters and keep attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mosaic

I have numerous individual 10m Raster files (with both quantitative and qualitative data) for each state and need to combine them into a national dataset.

However, when using a mosaic it seems that the attributes are not kept. I need to keep the attributes that I've already joined so I can conduct further analyses.

Is there an alternative to mosaic, sort of like the merge or append tools for polygons?

Comment: for arcgis use a mosaic dataset

Comment: I've tried that, and it didn't seem to include any of the data. In fact, it looked just like the mosaic result.

Comment: mosaic datasets (MDs) have attribute tables, so you should be able to keep all the input attributes from all your input rasters, and use the MD mosaic methods to get the proper looking image... this isn't a 'mosaic', which just burns rasters into one - a mosaic dataset keeps them all separate but mosaics on the fly for the client...

Comment: Yes, I know. I've been following the ESRI guides on building them, such as:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000039000000

But like I said, when I try with just a couple states to test, it doesn't bring in any attributes.

Comment: Might want to try GeoNet - you might need to do some post-loading joins on the data...

Comment: I guess it doesn't hurt to ask around. Thanks

Comment: So I've done some more digging and found that using the "Build Attribute Table" tool cannot be used on rasters that are 32bit floating point. Is that the same with mosaic datasets? Are they not able to use the attribute table of a 32bit floating raster?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this kind of functionality  is not available with ArcGIS (both MAP and PRO) anymore. Even with mosaic dataset the integer as datatype, the extra fields of the original raster was dropped.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the only other option would be to redo everything. I could mosaic the rasters and keep the unique identifier, and combine all the tables into one. Then I could join the national dataset to the one table... but that seems like a lot of unnecessary work. Perhaps I will look into other options like python or R. Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that this functionality was present once and since deprecated?

Comment: I know this because I had the arcpy script that was working fine in the older version of ArcMap. Upon updating I started getting an error because the extra attribute column that my script relied on was no more retained. Later I applied several approaches, including using the mosaic dataset approach, even changing the data types. None of the approach helped retain the attribute table upon mosaicking.